# DRF SearchFilter fixed field value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Hi there i would like to ask regarding the searchfilter class in this [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter).

> ```
> class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
>     queryset = User.objects.all()
>     serializer_class = UserSerializer
>     filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
>     search_fields = ('username', 'email')
> ```
>
> This will allow the client to filter the items in the list by making queries such as:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/api/users?search=russell
> ```

Now what i want to do is, for example add a `gender` field to `User` object and search filter it returning all male in the queryset.

It would be something like this `search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'gender="male"') # of course this wont work`.

How can we attain this thing in searchFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use filter_fields instead of the search field.

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,filters.DjangoFilterBackend)
    search_fields = ('username', 'email')
    filter_fields = ('gender',)
```

> URL: 
>   http://example.com/api/users?gender=male&&search=russell